# 3.Separation by parts

Tags: integration

Solve $y'(t)=-y+2z-1$ and $z'(t)=-z-2y-2$ with y(0)=7 and z(0)=6.

(My work based on one of the answers below-not completed)

Differentiating the first equation:
$$y'(t)=-y+2z-1$$
$$y"=-y'+2z'$$
$$y"+y'=2z'$$

Solving for z':
$$z'=\frac{y"+y'}{2}$$

Integrating z':
$$z=\frac{y'+y+1}{2}$$

substituting these values of z $z=\frac{y'+y+1}{2}$ and z′ $z'=\frac{y"+y'}{2}$ into the second equation to get an equation that has only y and its derivatives:

$$z'(t)=-z-2y-2$$
$$\frac{y"+y'}{2}=-\frac{y'+y+1}{2}-2y-2$$
$$(y"+y')=-(y'+y+1)-4y-4$$
$$y"+y'=-y'-y-1-4y-4$$
$$y"+2y'+5y=-5$$

My original (wrong) work:
Solve $y'(t)=-y+2z-1$ and $z'(t)=-z-2y-2$ with y(0)=7 and z(0)=6.

$$y'(t)=-y+2z-1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-y+2z-1$$
$$\frac{1}{(-y+2z-1)}dy=dt$$
$$\frac{1}{(y-2z+1)}dy=-dt$$
$$∫\frac{1}{(y-2z+1)}dy=-∫dt$$
$$ln|y-2z+1|=-t+C$$

Then to find C:

$$C=ln|y-2z+1|+t$$
$$C=ln|(7)-2(6)+1|+0$$
$$C=ln|8-12|$$
$$C=ln|-4|$$
$$C=ln(-4)$$

To get an equation for y:

$$ln|y-2z+1|=-t+C$$
$$e^{ln|y-2z+1|}=e^{-t+C}$$
$$|y-2z+1|=e^{-t+C}$$
$$|y-2z+1|=e^{-t}e^{C}$$
$$|y-2z+1|=\frac{e^{C}}{e^{-t}}$$

I am not sure, but can I remove the absolute value signs at this point? Then:

$$y-2z+1=\frac{e^{C}}{e^{-t}}$$
$$y=\frac{e^{C}}{e^{-t}}+2z-1$$
$$y=\frac{e^{ln(4)}}{e^{-t}}+2z-1$$
$$y=\frac{(4)}{e^{-t}}+2z-1$$

Solving for z:
$$z'(t)=-z-2y-2$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=-z-2y-2$$
$$\frac{1}{(-z-2y-2)}dz=dt$$
$$∫\frac{1}{(z+2y+2)}dz=-∫dt$$
$$ln|z+2y+2|=-t+C$$
$$C=ln|z+2y+2)|+t$$

Solvin for C:
$$C=ln|z+2y+2|+t$$
$$C=ln|(6)+2(7)+2|+0$$
$$C=ln|8+14|$$
$$C=ln|22|$$

Solving for z:
$$ln|z+2y+2|=-t+C$$
$$e^{ln|z+2y+2|}=e^{-t+C}$$
$$|z+2y+2|=e^{-t+C}$$
$$|z+2y+2|=e^{-t}e^{C}$$
$$|z+2y+2|=\frac{e^{C}}{e^t}$$

Once again I am not sure what to do about the absolute value sign, so I just remove it.I would like to know if this is correct (and the logic) or if this is not, and what to do alternatively.

$$z+2y+2=\frac{e^{C}}{e^t}$$
$$z=\frac{e^{C}}{e^t}-2y-2$$
$$z=\frac{e^{ln(22)}}{e^t}-2y-2$$
$$z=\frac{22}{e^t}-2y-2$$

Comment: @Amzoti kind of...a bit unclear on the concept though

Comment: Wrong from about line 3 on, where a $dx$ appears out of nowhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson its obviously a typo...and supposed to be dy

Comment: Good. So now the mistakes start on the 6th line. You can't integrate that way --- $z$ isn't a constant, it's a function of $t$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok....then how can I proceed?

Comment: I have amplified my solution.

Comment: Destructive edit rolled back. Do not attempt to do this again, or a moderator will have to get involved.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate the 1st equation: $y''=-y'+2z'$, so $z'=(1/2)(y''+y')$. Also from the 1st equation, $z=(1/2)(y'+y+1)$. Substitute these values of $z$ and $z'$ into the second equation to get an equation that has only $y$ and its derivatives. If I did the algebra right, it comes to $$y''+2y'+5y=-5$$ The solution to this will be $y=y_c+y_p$, where $y_c$ is the general solution to  $y''+2y'+5y=0$, and $y_p$ is any one solution to $y''+2y'+5y=-5$.

For $y''+2y'+5y=0$, we form the characteristic equation $r^2+2r+5=0$, which has solutions $r=-1\pm2i$. This means $y_c=e^{-t}(A\sin2t+B\cos2t)$, with $A$, $B$ arbitrary.

For $y''+2y'+5y=-5$, we look for a constant solution $y_p=C$, and we get $C=-1$.

So the general solution is $y=e^{-t}(A\sin2t+B\cos2t)-1$.

From this, and the original equations, you can get a formula for $z(t)$. Then, you can use the initial conditions to work out $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I understand how you got to that step but I am afraid I forgot how to solve that kind of equation..

Comment: So have you had a chance to look at the additional material?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not finished yet. You want to get $z(t)$ and $y(t)$, not $z(t,y)$.

You found: $y = 4e^t + 2z - 1$ and $z = 22e^{-t} - 2y - 2$.That would give $z = 22e^{-t} - 8e^t -4z \rightarrow z = \frac{22}{5} e^{-t} - \frac{8}{5} e^t$. Then $y = 8.8e^{-t} + 3.2e^t -1$.

Beyond that, **the absolute signs are an issue**. At one point, you had $\left|z+2y+2\right| = e^{C-t}$. This expression is extremely logical; the left side can be negative, but the right side can never be unless we're talking complex $C-t$, which we aren't.

Your solution splits into two distinct regions here; that's what the absolute signs do. So region $A$ is just $z+2 > -2y$ and region $B$ is $z+2<-2y$. You'll have to check, but there are a number of regions due to the two absolute values. These regions all have a slightly different equation.

So, as an example, suppose we would find $\left|x\right| = e^t$. You cannot say that $x=e^t$; that's too simple; it does not give the values for $x<0$. Instead, you state that $x = \begin{cases} e^t & x>0 \\ -e^t & x<0\end{cases}$.

This gives you all values for x; that's what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this analysis is based on the flawed work by OP.

Comment: So I shouldn't follow this?

Comment: Why don't you take the formulas given here for $y$ and $z$, and plug them back into the differential equations, and see whether they work?

Comment: Gerry is right, of course. I realised that while typing the post, so I put the "absolute sign issue" in bold to emphasise that the solution is wrong anyway. I did want to explain how the absolute signs feature in it, so I kept that in.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this system, one can introduce the functions $$(u(t),v(t))=(y(t)\mathrm e^t,z(t)\mathrm e^t),$$ note that $u'=(y'+y)\mathrm e^t$ and $v'=(z'+z)\mathrm e^t$ and deduce that your system is equivalent to $$u'=2v-\mathrm e^t,\qquad v'=-2u-2\mathrm e^t,$$ with the initial conditions $(u(0),v(0))=(7,6)$.

Can you proceed from there? For example, $u''=$ $______$ and $v''=$ $______$ hence...